# Why does this code work with F1 and not CTRL-M (for example)

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code online, and it works like a charm:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "WorkbooksHandler"
End Sub

Sub WorkbooksHandler()
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count <= 16 Then
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs"). _
    ShowPopup 500, 225
    Else
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs"). _
    Controls("More Sheets...").Execute
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I press F1 and it opens a dialogue with all the sheets. I can select the sheet I want and it goes there.

If I change the code just slightly, and use:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^{m}", "WorkbooksHandler"
End Sub
```

Now control-m opens with dialogue showing me the sheets, but when I click on the sheet I want excel doesn't navigate there. Why should the trigger make any difference, and make the execution not work?

Edit: By the way, the code also works fine when I run it manually with F5 as well, just not with the onkey control-m.

Comment: Please narrow down your question: is it still the original one or something else? Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell when I use the same Sub WorkbooksHandler() with a different trigger - Control-M instead of F1, then it doesn't execute properly anymore.

Comment: So, what is the error (exact definition instead of quite broadly defined "doesn't execute properly")? Rgds,

Comment: @AlexBell Sorry, I'll be clearer. Although the "Active" dialogue opens and it allows me to select the sheet I want to navigate to, Excel does not navigate to the selected sheet. It just stays in Sheet1 (or whatever active sheet I'm in at the time.)

Comment: Agree with @AlexBell, also it works well here except I do not have Controls("More sheets...") implemented

Comment: Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls("More Sheets...").Execute is roughly the equivalent of right clicking the arrows on the left the tabs of sheets

Comment: Can we confirm it is the commandbar functions that's not working? (i.e. ctrl-m works properly but it's the application.commandbar() giving errors)

Comment: @Alex Ctrl-m opens what looks like the correct commandbar. It just doesn't do what it's suppose to do (=navigate to a different sheet).

Comment: Which version of Excel? It works fine in 2010 for me with Ctrl+m

Comment: @Rory Really? I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce the behavior , works fine on my machine too

Comment: @Eliyahu it works well for me too.  Try putting the code in a new clear workbook and see.

Comment: Yes, really. Does it work for you if you load Excel in Safe Mode? (hold down the Ctrl key while starting Excel normally)

Comment: It does not work for me on 2010. It only fails if Control is part of the shortcut. Shift, Alt, or nothing works fine. It also works if you put a breakpoint on the Execute line. DoEvents and OnTime did not seem to help.

Comment: @DickKusleika Curiouser and curiouser. Which exact build of 2010? Mine is 14.0.7116.5000 (on Win 7 Enterprise)

Comment: @Rory  14.0.7015.1000 (32-bit) on Win 7 Professional SP1

Comment: @Rory Maybe I was too quick to post an answer. Does holding down the Control key while you open More Sheets work as expected?

Comment: @DickKusleika Your answer makes sense in terms of the behaviour - if I hold Ctrl while clicking the Sheets menu, it doesn't activate the sheet - but I'm not seeing it purely from the Ctrl key being in the shortcut. Not sure what could cause it - Windows, Office or hardware.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Alt (%) works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the Control key, when used with OnKey persists through the whole command even though you've no doubt released the key.  This has no effect on most things that you do, but inexplicably effects the More Sheets popup. Take this code

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^m", "WorkbooksHandler"
End Sub

Sub WorkbooksHandler()

    SendKeys "{RIGHT}"

End Sub
```

All that does is press the right arrow key. But it has the effect of pressing Ctrl+Right which takes you to the edge of you worksheet (for a blank worksheet). So the Control part of ^m is sticking around through the execution of WorkbooksHandler.

This happens manually also. Hold down the control key, right click on the sheet navigation buttons, select More Sheets, select a sheet. It doesn't move to that sheet when you have Control held down.

I tried all manner of SendKeys, OnTime, and DoEvents, but couldn't trick Excel into releasing the Control key. I'll bet you could find a Windows API that would do the trick, but it's probably easier to simply pick a key combination that doesn't use Control.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
Sub WorkbooksHandler()
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count <= 16 Then
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs"). _
    ShowPopup 500, 225
    Else
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs"). _
    Controls("More Sheets...").Execute
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

is pasted in  **Modules**,

Then 
Compile and Run the `Auto_Open()` manually then try the shortcut

Comment: I did, but that gives me the same result - opens the "Active" dialogue but doesn't navigate to the selected sheet.

Comment: When you say compile and run Auto_Open() manually, you mean F5 when active, correct?

Comment: Alt+F8 then choose Auto_Open from the list

Comment: where is Sub WorkbooksHandler() code located ? Under This work book or Module?

Comment: In Personal.XLSB under Modules within Module1